# How to fix Error: The getter 'elements2' isn 't defined for the class 'ListLiteral'. when creating string translations (.arb files)

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I am trying to generate string localizations file but when I run

```
flutter pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir="lib/l10n" lib/localization/localizations.dart
```

it shows this error:

```
Failed to precompile intl_translation:extract_to_arb:
file:///D:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl_translation-0.17.4/lib/src/intl_message.dart:94:22: Error: The getter 'elements2' isn
't defined for the class 'ListLiteral'.
 - 'ListLiteral' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('file:///D:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.34.3/lib/dart/a
st/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'elements2'.
    if (!identifiers.elements2.every((each) => each is SimpleIdentifier)) {
                     ^^^^^^^^^
```

By following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhsHGJEOSYM), I have added "l10n" to my lib https://1drv.ms/u/s!AijASouhGkzqhIkjFGQbx7Wg7knsVg (this is the screenshot that shows the lib directory I have)

this is my [localizations.dart](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AijASouhGkzqhIkkQgjm7ZhnrVf-6g) file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant but it might be the problem with ['analyzer' package version](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl_translation/issues/62). 
Try to upgrade your dependencies and/or add dependency override. It solved the problem for me.